# ignoring of operations outside of brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var x = 0;

var arr = [4,9,2];

arr[x] = (++x)-1;

document.write(arr[x]);//9
```

//Why js ignores minus that outside of brackets? Why is it 9 not 4?

Comment: please do not use this style. it is prone to errors and hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

This `(++x)-1` would result in 0 and the `x` would be 1 after the evaluation of this statement, since you have incremented it by 1 and it was assigned the value of 0.

So this `arr[x]` (in the statement `document.write(arr[x]);`) is actually `arr[1]` and `arr[1]` is assigned the value of 9.

Regarding the assignment:

```
arr[x] = (++x)-1;
```

Now the value of the first element of the array (with index 0) would be assigned the value 0. This is why if you print the arr you will get the following output:

```
[0,9,2]
```

Comment: But why? Shouldn't arr[x] will equal the result of whole operation?

Comment: @hawkeye871 I am sorry but I don't get your comment? What you mean by saying that `arr[x]` will equal the result of the whole operation?

Comment: @hawkeye871, you have changed value of first element in array: https://jsfiddle.net/yu1m5eg3/ so, 4 is 0 now... (if that was intention) But x is 1 (you've incremented it) and array[1] is 9, of course.

Answer (score 1):

you write to

```
arr[x]  // which is arr[0]
(++x)-1; // 1-1 = 0, x = 1
```

then you write out

```
document.write(arr[x]); //arr[1] which is 9
```

> Why js ignores minus that outside of brackets?

so no, js does not ignore the minus. Maybe try to understand the prefix `++` operator wtthout using arrays, since they confused you a bit in this case.

Example:

```
var x = 0, y = 0;
y = (++x) - 1;
document.write("x: " +x + " y: " y); //x == 1, y == 0
```

Comment: @hawkeye871 no problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Basically this with prefix [increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_())

```
++x - 1
```

is the same as the use of x with a postfix increment.

```
x++
```

Answer (score 0):

> `arr[0] = 0`, here `x` incremented by 1 so, `x` = 1, (1)-1 = 0
>
> `arr[1]` will print 9 because `x` = 1 , you are accessing the array
>   element with index 1
>
> `document.write(arr)` it will print `[0,9,2]` ,because the first
>   element of the array (with index 0) would be assigned the value 0.

```
var x = 0;

var arr = [4,9,2];

arr[x] = (++x)-1;    
// x would be 1 after the evaluation of this statement.

//document.write(x);// it will print 1 

document.write(arr[x]);// arr[1] it will print 9

//document.write(arr);// it will print [0,9,2]
```